# how do I add a reset button for my two TextViews in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, button, textview, android-studio-4.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/away"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="@string/away"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/_0"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:onClick="score1"
        android:text="@string/score" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/home"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="@string/_0"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="score2"
        android:text="@string/score" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reset"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textColor="#ff1100"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I searched it on multiple websites but I still can't the answer. I  also tried using the__setText("")it

didn't work as well as the the if() method. I have also tried the intent method also doesn't seem to

work, and many other codes , please help me because I am stuck at this bit , I know that it is simple but

I just can't find it. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here? If you want a button to perform an action upon clicking you need to either add xml tag of click function to perform or add an onClickListener to it in your .java class

Comment: You have to add more details and7 clarify Your problem. What do You want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following codes will set the TextView `score` to blank when Button `one` is clicked

**First approach**

To use the `android:onClick="score1"` in your XML

Add this to your activity

```
TextView mTvScore1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score)

public void score1(View v) {
    mTvScore1.setText("");
}
```

**Second approach**

```
Button mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one)
TextView mTvScore1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score)

mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTvScore1.setText("");
    }
});
```

**Activity code**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView mTvScore1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        Button mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);

        mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                score1(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void score1(View v) {
        mTvScore1.setText("");
    }
}
```